# f:selectItems tag not executed

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

View:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{studentBean.gender}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{studentBean.genderList()}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Model:

```
public static ArrayList<String> genderList(){
    ArrayList<String> genders = new ArrayList<String>();
    try{
        genders.add("Male");
        genders.add("Female");
        genders.add("Others");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return genders;
}
```

HTML output:

```
<f:selectitems value="[Male, Female, Others]"></f:selectitems>
<select name="createStudentForm:j_idt27" size="1"></select>
```

Here is the user interface with drop down, which is not populated, any idea?

[image: OutPut Image for HTML DropDown]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. I improved your title and tags. Please always create a [mcve] for the problem you have. See also http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info and also compare your code (java and xhtml) with a working example in a modern tutorial and look for differences (hint: most likely namespace declaration related)

Comment: please don't use three backtics for highlighting multiple lines of code but use indentation wit four spaces, beginning on new lines with an empty line before

Comment: @Kukeltje Thanks for the guidance. I am going through.